# How do I resolve error "Operator '>' is not supported for operands of type 'function_handle'" in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

The purpose of this iterative function is to update two parameters of my function to keep output values within a desired range (19 to 21)
Here is what I have so far

```
for i = 2:tw
T1f(i) = dT1(i,T1(i-1),T2(i-1))+T1(i-1);
T2f(i) = dT2(i,T1(i-1),T2(i-1))+T2(i-1);

if ((T1f(i) > 21) | (T2f(i) > 21)) && dT1f > 0
    k2f(i:(i+1799)) = k2f(i)-2;
    Qfin(i:(i+1799)) = Qfin(i)-500;
    N = N+1;
elseif ((19 > T1f(i)) | (19 > T2f(i))) && 0 > dT1f
    k2f(i:i+1799) = k2f(i)+2;
    Qfin(i:(i+1799)) = Qfin(i)+500;
    N = N+1;
end
k2f = max(k2f,10);
k2f = min(k2f,1);
Qfin = max(Qfin,2500);
Qfin = max(Qfin,0);

end
```

I keep receiving the error Operator '>' is not supported for operands of type 'function_handle for the elseif line, but not at the if line. Why is this and how to I remedy it? Any suggestions about a better way to acheive this would also be appreciated.
Full file will be below.

```
k1 = 0.2; %W/m^2
k2 = 1750; % W/m^2, constant
k3 = 0.5; %W/m^2
Ain = 0.5; %m^2
Cair = 1005; %J/kg*K
Pair = 1.2; %kg/m^3
Qin = 2500; %W/m^2 constant
L = 5; %m
W = 6; %m
H = 3; %m H1 = H2 = H
T1o = 5; %C
T2o = 7; %C
N = 1;

% Calculating Areas and volumes
Awalls = 2*((L*H)+(W*H)); %m^2
Aceiling = W*L; %m^2
Aroof = sqrt((W*L)^2+(L*H*2)^2)+W*H; %
Vup = W*H*L/2; %m^3
Vdown = W*H*L; %m^3

%Initializing Arrays and Values
tw = 86400*2; %number of seconds in two days
t = [1:1:tw]; %array with integers 1-tw
n = length(t); 
T = zeros(1,n);
T1 = zeros(1,n);
T2 = zeros(1,n);
T1f = zeros(1,n);
T2f = zeros(1,n);
T1(1) = T1o;
T2(1) = T2o;
T1f(1) = T1o;
T2f(1) = T2o;

%% Setting Q values
Qfin = zeros(1,n); %Qin for fluctuation
Qfin(1) = 2500;
%% Setting k2 values
k2f = zeros(1,n); %k3 for fluctuation
kf(1) = 10;

%% Defining Functions
Tout = @(t,T) -10*sin(2*pi*t/86400);
%Constant k2/Qin
dT1 = @(t,T1,T2) ((Ain*Qin)-(Aceiling*k2*(T1-T2-5))-(Awalls*k1*(T1- 
Tout(t))))/(Cair*Pair*Vdown);
dT2 = @(t,T1,T2) ((Aceiling*k2*(T1-T2-5))-(Aroof*k3*(T2-Tout(t))))/(Cair*Pair*Vup);
%Fluctuating k2/Qin
dT1f = @(t,T1,T2) ((Ain*Qfin(t))-(Aceiling*k2f(t)*(T1-T2-5))-(Awalls*k1*(T1- 
Tout(t))))/(Cair*Pair*Vdown);
dT2f = @(t,T1,T2) ((Aceiling*k2f(t)*(T1-T2-5))-(Aroof*k3*(T2-Tout(t))))/(Cair*Pair*Vdown);


%% Iterate for constant k2/Qin with Euler's
for i = 2:tw
T1(i) = dT1(i,T1(i-1),T2(i-1))+T1(i-1);
T2(i) = dT2(i,T1(i-1),T2(i-1))+T2(i-1);
end


%% Iteratre for fluctuation
for i = 2:tw
T1f(i) = dT1(i,T1(i-1),T2(i-1))+T1(i-1);
T2f(i) = dT2(i,T1(i-1),T2(i-1))+T2(i-1);

if ((T1f(i) > 21) | (T2f(i) > 21)) && dT1f > 0
    k2f(i:(i+1799)) = k2f(i)-2;
    Qfin(i:(i+1799)) = Qfin(i)-500;
    N = N+1;
elseif ((19 > T1f(i)) | (19 > T2f(i))) && 0 > dT1f
    k2f(i:i+1799) = k2f(i)+2;
    Qfin(i:(i+1799)) = Qfin(i)+500;
    N = N+1;
end
k2f = max(k2f,10);
k2f = min(k2f,1);
Qfin = max(Qfin,2500);
Qfin = max(Qfin,0);

end
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. The error is correct you use the operator for a function handle. It doesnt matter where in your code you use it like that, it wont work. Have you considered to call it like `0> dT1f(t(i),T1(i),T2(i))`? It is a function so it needs input.

Comment: What do you expect that `dT1f > 0` does, given that `dT1f` is a function? You cannot mathematically compare a function to an integer. What you (probably?) want, is to know where that function is larger than zero, thus you need to evaluate your function before comparing it.